# Jwplayer e Google drive link direto

Tags: php, javascript

estou fazendo um sistema é cheguei em uma parte que tenho que adicionar um vídeo que está no Google drive, gostaria de saber se há alguma forma que eu possa fazer tal função utilizando o jwplayer ou se há uma forma de criar um link direto do filme

PS: O vídeo excede o tamanho máximo para verificação do antivirus que o Google drive utiliza.

Comment: Adicione o código daquilo que já tem até agora

Comment: @Cʜᴜɴ então nesse caso estou completamente perdida, não sei por onde começar,